# Where should I ask about code design and implementation?

Tags: discussion, scope, help-improvement

I recently asked a question (intially badly) about how I would implement a UI pattern with React not problems I was having with code. The question was ultimately closed due to being off topic.

Where should I ask questions about code design pattern implementation?

Comment: You could try to take a look at [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and see if your question might fit their scope.

Comment: Shortcut: read [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) over on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ivarni thanks mate, I'll try asking there next time. :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey that's super useful thanks mate